# Map a remote CIFS share in a Windows client through a third server

Tags: windows, proxy, cifs

My desktop machine is a Windows 7 PC. I need to access some file shares on the remote Windows server `JASON` using a set of Windows credentials. However, the server `JASON` is behind a firewall, so to access it I normally have to connect to a special VPN.

However, I do not want to use the VPN as the VPN messes up my other network access. What I would rather do is connect through a third server `BASTION` that is behind the same firewall as `JASON`. I have an account on `BASTION` that I can use SSH to access.

```
                                 Firewall
                          .-------------------.
WINDOWS 7 --> port 22 -.  | BASTION --> JASON |
                       |  |  ^                |
                       '-----'                |
                          |                   |
                          '-------------------'
```

How can I map the remote share on `JASON` to my Windows 7 machine using `BASTION` as a proxy. I am thinking I can use the putty client, but I do not know the next steps.

Comment: I do not think this is possible. Why does VPN mess up your network?

Comment: When the VPN is on it blocks me from other servers that are not behind the firewall and do not allow machines behind the firewall to access them.

Answer (score 1):

You should rather fix your VPN. If you're using Windows built-in VPN, try:

On the VPN Connection properties:

`-> Networking -> Internet Protocol Version 4 -> Advanced... -> Unceck "Use default gateway on remote network"`

This ensures that you are NOT using the VPN's default gateway, but your local one. You should retain network access to your local network.

Comment: I am using the Cisco VPN Client, not the Microsoft one.

Comment: Can you try their AnyConnect client?
http://superuser.com/questions/284709/how-to-allow-local-lan-access-while-connected-to-cisco-vpn